Mass control over many BLE Spinner Hats
Very Novice!
Is the following a possibility?
Scenario:
200 people on a football field with Bluetooth controlled spinner hats that use the nrf52832
The spinner hats (the ones with a propeller on top) do not need a pairing code and will pair to any phone with the app but only to one phone.
Is it possible to command them all using a robust PC and a larger transmitter to spin at the same speed, and able to change that speed every 250 milliseconds with minimal latency?
I tested speed control on the spinner hats with a single phone. Very minimal latency in this configuration.

The phrase "a larger transmitter" is a direct contradiction of the phrase "Bluetooth Low Energy", don't you think? ;)  BLE certainly supports a mesh topology, where a set of devices forward the messages amongst themselves.

The simple answer is no, it is not possible. The extended answer is yes with some additional limitations/requirements. One of them: you need to have ability to modify hat's firmware.
